# SQL Windows Auth

Tags: asp.net, sql, security, authentication, windows-authentication

I have a local test environment set up with IIS. I'm using the connection string below to connect with c# in the codebehind of an ASPX page using my windows auth. I am getting the error that [PCNAME]/ASPNET login failed. Why is the user name ASPNET attempting to login when I've specified my connection string to use my login?

```
user id=[UID];password=[PASS];server=[LOCALSERVER];database=db_specialOps;Trusted_Connection=yes
```

Comment: More than likely, you are not actually using that connection string.  How are you opening the connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/sql-server-connection-string-trusted-connection-true-issue

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor I looked it over, and it does help a bit, but I'm not sure it gives me a clear answer/fix. Thanks though. It does help clarify some bits.

Comment: @MystereMan I am using the connection string for certain. I have created and SqlConnection and called Open(). Then using and SqlCommand with the SqlConnection through an SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 3):

Trusted authentication uses the credentials of the user that is executing the process.  If it is specified as yes, then the username and password in your connection string are ignored.

In this case, the ASPNET user account is the user that is running the process, so this is the account that is being used to connect to SQL Server.

Checking, another SO question addresses this issue.

[When using Trusted_Connection=true and SQL Server authentication, will this effect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642483/sql-server-connection-string-trusted-connection-true-issue)

Comment: If Trusted_Connection isn't there, my authentication fails for my windows authentication uid. If it is, I get the ASPNET error. My UID is set as the sa for the entire server and the dbo for the database in question.

Comment: Can I ask why you are not just creating a SQL Server service account for exclusive use by your application?  This is the strategy used in pretty much every app I've written.

Comment: I'm attempting to replicate the production environment as much as possible. a simple SQL auth would work fine in test, but windows auth would provide a more robust test environment if it's possible.

Comment: So to clarify, it is a requirement on the production server to use Windows authentication? What are you getting out from that strategy what you can't get with a service account?  Just trying to understand your situation so that I can provide an answer that helps as well as explains the situation.

Comment: So I checked a little deeper. We use windows authentication and SQL authentication mixed. My UID is added as a user under logins and under the specific database users. The login is set to use windows authentication in the properties. I'd like to be able to login with that. I've got server auth working fine using my own added user. At this point, I'd really like to just satisfy my curiosity on the windows auth bit.

Comment: Fair enough, but know that going the Windows auth route is normally a no-no.  Would you really want your users logging into that DB *as you* in production?  Do you want to store your domain password in a .config file?  Are there any corporate policies that mandate the changing of passwords every n days?  These are all considerations under the Windows auth route (there are more).

Comment: Thanks. Normally in production we don't use our personal logins, but I started to get curious about the possibilities and wanted to run with the idea at least to a working prototype. I appreciate the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Trusted_Connection=yes` part of the connection string. It tells the sql client library to connect to the sql server, using the Windows auth, with the current process' Windows identity. In the ASP.NET case that is `[PCNAME]/ASPNET`. That's why you see that error message.

If you want to use sql auth, just supply username and password as you do - without the `Trusted_Connection=yes` part.

Comment: I'm using my windows authentication, not sql auth. I thought the Trusted_Connection was required in this case.

Comment: When using Windows Auth, you cannot specify a username and password in the connection string. Instead, set the identity of the ASP.NET application pool.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string for Windows authentication:

```
connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

OR

```
connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

No user/pass

---

Connection string for SQL authentication with user/pass

```
connectionString="Server=MyServer; Database=pubs; User Id=MyUser; password= P@ssw0rd"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Also see this question, might help you: 
[Connect to SQL Server using windows authentication and specific account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065972/connect-to-sql-server-using-windows-authentication-and-specific-account)

Comment: alright, so I understand the windows auth versus the sql auth bit. My user id is added into the security/logins section as an sql user using windows authentication. However, when I try to connect using the specific user and pass with my user name, it doesn't work. This method worked fine in production.